# Spring date conventer

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm looking for elegant way to parse data in two ways
1. Backend "int date" -> Front end "string date"
2. Frontend "string date -> Backend "int date"

I was trying to do something like this:

```
public class SimpleTable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  long id;

  @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
  @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
  @ElementCollection(targetClass = Date.class)
  List<Date> dates;
}
```

But this seems to not working because this is a response:

```
[{"dates":[1512601200000,1494280800000,1488150000000,1485385200000,1494367200000,1489791600000,1506204000000,1509750000000,1495836000000,1509228000000]}]
```

Can somebody correct me?

Comment: In spring mvc this balise help you convert Date @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd") may be it can help you in your case

Comment: Thanks for response. I found also this one "spring.jackson.date-format=yyyy-MM-dd"

Comment: In your contexte I guess it would be better to use spring.jackson.date-format=yyyy-MM-dd because Jackson is what convert your java object in rest